# Azure dev ops conflict merge

Tags: azure, merge, azure-devops, commit

So we have a code repo in Azure Dev Ops and two people working on the project. Being used to TFS we are adapting to Dev Ops and Git.
My co worker has commited and pushed three commits over the current code base. Meanwhile I have changed multiple files and have four commits to push into DevOps.

My co worker has left and I need to sort out the repo to get it back on track

All advice gratefully received. Will be looking at how I merge all of these files. 
Please be gentle I am a newbie at Git and more used to TFS
Thanks

Comment: This question is not a good fit for SO. Please refer to [ask]. What's the real question? How to merge in general? How to merge your specific issues?

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at the documentation [Resolve merge conflicts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/merging?view=azure-devops&tabs=visual-studio&viewFallbackFrom=vsts)

In short:

> 1. You'll be informed of the merge conflict(s) when you pull changes or attempt to merge two branches.
>    2. The conflict notification appears. Click the Conflicts link to start resolve file conflicts.
>    [image: conflicts]
>    <sub>(source: [microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/_img/merge_prompt_vs.png?view=vsts))</sub>

3. This will bring up a list of files with conflicts. Selecting a file lets you accept the changes in the source branch you are merging from with the Take Source button or accept the changes in the branch you are merging into using Keep Target. You can manually merge changes by selecting Merge, then entering the changes directly into the merge tool specified in your Git settings.
4. Use the checkboxes next to the lines modified to select between remote and local changes entirely, or edit the results directly in the Result editor under the Source and Target editor in the diff view.
5. When done making changes, click Accept Merge . Repeat this for all conflicting files.
6. Open the Changes view in Team Explorer and commit the changes to create the merge commit and resolve the conflict.
   [image: Merge in Visual Studio]
   <sub>(source: [microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/_img/vsmerge.gif?view=vsts))</sub>

Comment: I did see that however did not see how to Merge in Visual Studio. I usually sync. It fails on the Sync and then tells me to look in the output window which is empty.

Comment: Try just _pulling_, that should bring the changes from the repo to your local machine, triggering a merge.